# How to label nodes in a Hasse diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, nodes, labels

In this question I'm using the term *label* in the traditional sense of word. I clarify this because I'm under the impression that this is also a technical term within the TeX universe.

The code

```
\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{tikz}

  \begin{document}
   \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

      \node (u) at (0,0) {$\circ$};
      \node [below left  of=u] (e)  {$\circ$};
      \node [below right of=u] (f) {$\circ$};
      \node [below right of =e] (d) {$\circ$};

      \draw [black, shorten <=-7pt, shorten >=-6.6pt] (u) -- (e);
      \draw [black, shorten <=-7pt, shorten >=-6.6pt] (u) -- (f);
      \draw [black, shorten <=-7pt, shorten >=-6.6pt] (e) -- (d);
      \draw [black, shorten <=-7pt, shorten >=-6.6pt] (f) -- (d);

    \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{center}
  \end{document}
```

yields

[image: hasse diagram]

How can I label the nodes in the following fashion?

[image: Labeled hasse diagram]

Comment: I'm very inexperienced with both LaTeX and this S.E. site. Let me know how I can improve the question.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks, it seems to be exactly what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `label` to label the nodes as `label=above:u`. Further, you can define a node style and use it like

```
\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt}
    }
```

and `\draw`ing becomes easy as can be seen from this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt}
}
  \begin{document}
   \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

      \node [mynode,label=above:u] (u) at (0,0) {};
      \node [mynode,below left  = of u,label=left:e] (e)  {};
      \node [mynode,below right = of u,label=right:f] (f) {};
      \node [mynode,below right = of e,label=below:d] (d) {};

      \draw (u) -- (e) 
            (u) -- (f) 
            (e) -- (d) 
            (f) -- (d);

    \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{center}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If it's not too far from the scope of the question, may you tell me how can I shorten the distance between the label and the node?

Comment: Thank you very much. This is perfect. Can you explain to me what parameter makes the lines touch the circles and not cross into them?

Comment: @GitGud It is the normal nature of nodes. When you say `\draw (a) -- (b);` the lines are drawn from the edge of the nodes. But when you say `\draw (a.center) -- (b.center);` only then the line is drawn from the center.

Comment: Hm..But in the code I posted, if you zoom is you can see that the lines cross into the circle. If I remove `shorten <=-7pt, shorten >=-6.6pt`, then the lines will be very short and won't connect with the nodes.

Comment: @GitGud Oh. It is the `inner sep` and `outer sep` values. If you remove the shorten then the lines are `inner sep + outer sep` away from the center. Hope that is helpful.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, I have a question regarding a tangential problem. Sometimes I want to 'skip' nodes (that is, I want to declare a node, but I want an empty space to be there instead of an actual node). With your proposed solution, I can't achieve that because all nodes are automatically circles. How can I adapt it to sometimes have circles and sometimes 'nothing'? I tried removing the parameter *circle* from \tikzset but it didn't work.

Comment: @GitGud Remove `draw` also. And change `inner sep` value accordingly. Don't remove `draw,circle` from `tikzset`, whenever you want an empty node, use `\node [inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt,below right = of e,label=below:d] (d) {};`

Comment: I'm retarded. I had already done this before, but I forgot completely. So weird. Thanks a bunch.