# How to get enumerated captions below Tikz pictures?

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions

I did some dirty stuff in order to get the captions (i) and (ii) as seen below.

[image: tikzwithcap]

Basically what I did was add nodes (i) and (ii). The code used was basically the one given in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233398/25723) answer. It might be important to mention that this was done within two minipages, each with its own tikzpicture.

How can I do this in a proper way?

An ideal solution would contemplate different sorts of enumerations (letters, numerals, etc).

Comment: I would put the two diagrams into two different `tikzpicture`s and then use the `subfig` package to add the captions as normal figures

Comment: The "proper way" IMHO is that the captions should be done in the document itself, not in the graphics code. _C.f._ the [`subcaption` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption).

Comment: Thank you both for the comments, I'll look into it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have been advised  already to use `subcaption` package in the comments for the job. This answer tells you how to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\roman{subfigure})}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{paren}{(#2}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=paren}
\begin{document}
     \begin{figure}[htb]
       \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw (0,0) -- (2,0);
          \draw[fill=white] (0,0) circle (3pt) (2,0) circle(3pt);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
       \end{subfigure}
       \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw[fill=white] (0,0) circle (3pt) (2,0) circle(3pt);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
       \end{subfigure}
     \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To align the figures at the bottom, you can use `\subcaptionbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\roman{subfigure})}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{paren}{(#2}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=paren}
\begin{document}
     \begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \subcaptionbox{}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw (0,-3) -- (2,0);
          \draw[fill=white] (0,-3) circle (3pt) (2,0) circle(3pt);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \hfil
       \subcaptionbox{}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \draw[fill=white] (0,0) circle (3pt) (2,0) circle(3pt);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
     \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you are using `tikzpicture`, you can also use the `baseline` option to `tikzpicture` to adjust the base line.

Comment: It seems to be working fine, but due to me drawing diagrams of different heights, the captions end up not being aligned. Should I draw the diagrams from (0,0) and up to fix this or is this a bad workaround?

Comment: @GitGud Use `\subcaptionbox` as in the update.

Comment: @GitGud `\You \are \welcome` ;-)